# angularjs bind to $scope value from printed html in template

Tags: angularjs

I would like to store part of my html template to the backend. I can print the html value using ng-bind-html but if that html contains angular it is not parsed. e.g. consider that at some point the controller fetches a value $scope.myValue  . If i fetch the partial html from the backend that prints myValue "{{::myValue}}" this value is not parsed. Page displays "{{::myValue}}" instead of the actual value. So the controller fetches 2 things. The actual value of myValue and the partial html that prints it. Is there a way to force angular to parse the printed angular contents ? The point is to build a simple cms mechanism.

Thank you very much. Your replies are appreciated.

Comment: Some options are `ng-include` core directive or manually use `$compile()` in a controller or directive. With that said angular directives can pull server side templates in with the `templateUrl` set to server path. Creating a custom directive for basic scope/template can be done in minutes

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that if the directive tag is in the backend html it will not be called either.

Comment: No reason it shouldn't be if `angular.module('someModName').directive(...` is including in the app

Comment: Thank you again, i will try it. Is a manual $compile() with ng-repeat considered performance overkill ?